# Using Sqlcipher with sqlite-net in MonoTouch

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, sqlcipher, sqlite-net

I have an ios app in MonoTouch where i have to add encryption to my database. The database is created using sqlite-net libraries (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). 
Is it possible to use Sqlcipher with sqlite-net?

The sample i found is using Ado.net. works fine..
How to integrate Sqlcipher with sqlite-net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCipher for Xamarin has included support for sqlite-net.  We show a usage example with sqlite-net in the [Getting Started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-ios) page.

Comment: In case of Sqlite-net do i have to include "using Mono.Data.Sqlcipher;" I am little confused here.. Sqlcipher is the library to encrypt the sqlite database, correct? so when i am using sqlite-net i dont incluse Sqlcipher. I directly add support for using Mono.Data.Sqlite; Then add a password to my database. but dont know whether it is encrypting my database. If so what data encryption techniques (such as AES256) it is using ?

Comment: Nick again so if i have Sqlite-net then i dont have to include Sqlcipher libarary in the project? With Sqlite-net i will just add the password and it will encrypt the database for me? If it is true then what data encryption technique it is using???

Comment: @mobiletest No, you would not include {using Mono.Data.Sqlcipher}. Instead, add the same assembly, but place {using SQLite;} at the top of your source file. Be sure to use the constructor that takes a password (e.g. {new SQLiteConnection (FilePath, Password)}). Then SQLCipher will automatically encrypt data, details on the encryption are available at http://sqlcipher.net/design/. You should be able to extract the database from the device / emulator to verify that the data is encrypted, as illustrated on the design page.

Comment: Thanks Stephen and Nick

Comment: @Nick Parker link has 404'd [here is a link it could have possibly been from google](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin?version=2.1.1.4)